# Virus detected. how do I remove it?

Tags: macos, virus

[image]

How to fix this?
I am on High Sierra.
I can't purchase, Help!

Comment: .exercise files are not runnable on macos where did the.exe come from?

Comment: @Mark - You can still have .exes on the machine - they can't run unless you've got Boot Camp or a VM, but they can be present.

Comment: Which "antivirus" software are you using? As said in an answer download a free and safe (Avast for instance) antivirus before purchasing anything.

Answer (score 6):

First get another antivirus & see if it agrees.

Google 'Mac free antivirus'. Pick one you've already heard of.

If it agrees you just saved yourself some money.

If it disagrees, then there are 3 possibilities.

1. The first antivirus was more accurate.
2. The first antivirus was **less** accurate & is showing false positives.
3. The first antivirus just wanted to scare you into buying it.

We may never know which.

If you can find the files referenced, you can upload them to [Virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com/#/home/upload) for further evaluation.

Comment: I downloaded Avast, it removed that.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to back things up to an external drive, then wipe and reinstall the app.

Since this in an exe file, you won’t likely have it run on the new system and can get a nice free tool like MalwareBytes Mac software to clean things.

- https://www.malwarebytes.com/mwb-download/